# How to store local files in public folder in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, single-page-application, vercel

I have a NextJs project, today I tried to deploy it and found a lot of mistakes.

I have many images and pdf/doc files and I need to show img and download files with button.

All files stored in Public folder [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpOzH.png)

But I get this error with the files (pdf/doc) locally `Module not found: Can't resolve '/catalogs/...`. And get the same error with images in deploy.

I tried to move all files to public folder, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The public folder is the "right" way to place static pdfs/images.

Imaging you have placed all your PDFs in the `/public/pdf` folder and your project hosted at `http://localhost:3000`

You can access your images/pdf from the browser by typing

`http://localhost:3000/pdf/{file_name}.pdf`

For the component side, you don't need to type basePath (e.g. localhost), you can do it directly like this.

```
import Link from 'next/link'


...

<Link href="/pdf/file_name.pdf" locale={false}>...</Link>
```